# PyCharm + Qt Designer: window closes instantly

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pycharm, designer

The first day I try to deal with the GUI. The problem is that the window instantly closes (or does not open at all) when launched in the Python interpreter from under Windows OS when you double-click on the program file. The .py file association with the Python interpreter is set correctly. Saving as .pyw does not change anything. In debug mode in PyCharm and when launched via the Windows console, the program opens and closes correctly. This does not happen with files that work on the command line and use the input() function. Also, when typing the python -v command, a long report is issued, it’s not clear why, maybe this is the problem?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
 
counter = 0
 
 
class MainForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('MainForm.ui', self)
        self.IncBtn.clicked.connect(self.evt_inc_btn_clicked)
 
    def evt_inc_btn_clicked(self):
        global counter
        counter += 1
        self.CounterLbl.setText('Количество нажатий: ' + str(counter))
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWind = MainForm()
    MainWind.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]
[image]

A lot of things, nothing helps. I want a GUI application to run in Windows when double-clicking the left mouse button on a file with .py code.

MainForm.ui:

[image: MainForm.ui]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainForm</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainForm">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>550</width>
    <height>350</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainForm</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="CounterLbl">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>140</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>231</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Times New Roman</family>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Количество нажатий: 0</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="IncBtn">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>210</x>
      <y>130</y>
      <width>91</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Times New Roman</family>
      <pointsize>16</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Inc +1</string>
    </property>
    <property name="autoExclusive">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="autoDefault">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="default">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="flat">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Hi, I see that you are trying to read your UI from MainForm.ui, can you attach your MainForm.ui in your question too? If you refer your code from a tutorial, please do attach the tutorial link.

Comment: Just to double confirm, you want to open the .py file via double clicking on the .py file? I don't think you can do it. The only way to open a .py file is only via console. If you want to create an exe file, you can try reading into pyinstaller.

Comment: Not an .exe file, but to associate .py files with the Python interpreter. I use Anaconda and, unlike IDLE, 
this cannot be done there, since there are many development environments used there and the necessary 
environment must be activated before running the .py file. You can't do without writing a .bat file. 
I've never done this and I don't know cmd syntax. I found how to activate the environment I need, but I 
can't open the file I need in it:

@echo off
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\Joanit\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\Joanit\anaconda3\envs\Study

Comment: I already agree that the path to the file be set statically, but ideally, of course, the desired file should 
be passed as an argument.Next, you need to somehow go to the folder I need and run the .py file I need in the 
already activated environment, something like:

@cd /d d:\Download
python 1.py

But it doesn't work. And write all these commands in several lines in one .bat file, but I don't know the cmd 
syntax.

Answer (score 2):

if you read the error message it clearly states:

```
Warning: This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment please see https://conda.io/activation
```

you cannot use conda environments as "double click" target because you need to activate the environment first.

if you really need the double click thing you either.

1. make a `.bat` file and activate the environment using `conda activate X` then launch python pointed to your .py file, in the same .bat script.
2. use a system python installation from [python.org](https://www.python.org/)